# Simple java client code for Web Service - something to do with QName?

Tags: java, web-services, client, rpc

I am getting the following error when I get to the line that invokes a REALLY BASIC web service I have running on Tomcat/Axis.

```
Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName
```

Have I got something wrong with QName?- I can't even find any useful information about it.

My client code is below:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;

    public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try{
            String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/TestWebService/services/DoesMagic";  

            Service service = new Service();
            Call call = (Call) service.createCall();

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
            call.setOperationName( new QName("http://testPackage.fc.com/, doBasicStuff") );

            String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {"some kind of message"} );

            System.out.println(ret);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

My web serivce code is really basic - just a simple class that returns your input string with a bit of concat text:

```
public String doBasicStuff(String message)
    {
        return "This is your message: " + message;

    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using wsdl2java with Axis to generate proxy classes for the web service and it's methods? I can't tell if you're just writing some sample/test code, but usually you don't need to use the Call object or invoke() methods on your own. wsd2ljava might save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the exception says, you call the QName constructor incorrectly:

```
new QName("http://testPackage.fc.com/, doBasicStuff")
```

is incorrect. I think you have to pass two strings, one containing the namespace, one the localname. The documentation will typically contain a description on how to use that class.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be a typo in your QName?:

```
new QName("http://testPackage.fc.com/", "doBasicStuff")
```

instead of:

```
new QName("http://testPackage.fc.com/, doBasicStuff")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of these:

```
public QName(String localPart)     or
public QName(final String namespaceURI, final String localPart)
```

but
    new QName("http://testPackage.fc.com/, doBasicStuff")
is wrong, since both values are in the same string ".., .."

Regards

Answer (score 0):

new QName("soapenc:string", "doBasicStuff")

Answer (score 0):

Just type the name of metod that have to on your case it would be 
`call.setOperationName("doBasicStuff");`